# Sticky Footer With Flexbox (Safari Issue)

Tags: html, css, safari

I have created a sticky footer with the flex box method. It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but when I open my site in Safari there seems to be space beneath my footer. How do I get rid of this space and make sure that the footer always stays at the bottom?

Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#wrapper {
    flex:1;
    -webkit-flex:1;
    min-width:1100px;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    min-height:100vh;
    -webkit-flex-direction:column;
    -webkit-display:flex;
    -webkit-min-height:100vh;
    min-height:100%;
}

header {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background:black;
    margin:0 auto;

}

.logo{
    padding-left:10px;
    float:left;
    padding-top:5px;
}

.chapter-logo {
    float:right;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

/* Start MENU styling*/

.menu{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 ;
    text-align:center;
    clear:both
}

ul.menu {
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    border-left:solid 1px #22674A;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:center;
}

ul.menu > li {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    width:20%;
    border-style:1px #22674A;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
}

/*START sub menu styling*/

ul.menu li:first-child a {
    border-left:none;
}

ul.menu ul li:first-child {
    border-bottom:solid 1px #22674A;
}

ul.menu ul li:nth-child(2) {
    border-bottom:solid 1px #22674A;
}

ul.menu ul li:last-child{
    border-bottom:none;
}

ul.menu ul li a {
    border:none;
}
ul.menu ul {
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    position: absolute;
    padding:0;
    border-left:none;
    border:solid 1px #22674A;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;

}
ul.menu a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    color: #22674A;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-left:solid 1px #22674A; 
}
ul.menu li {
    list-style: none;
}

/* End MENU styling */

/* Banner Styling*/
.index {
    height:400px;
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/RI05og7.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 400px;
}

.letter{
    width:460px;
    height:250px;
    margin-left:20px;
    line-height:1.75em;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif
}

h4 {
    color:#22674A;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
}

/*End of Banner Styling*/

/*News Styling*/
.news-section {
    height:350px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    width:100%;
}

.news  {
    width:812px;
    height:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.greekgod {
    width:250px;
    height:230px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    text-align:center;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    line-height:1.5em;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-right:30px;
    padding:5px;
}

.donate-button {
    width:150px;
    height:40px;
    border:3px solid black;
    background:#22674A;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:7px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:45px;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
.kovacs {
    width:250px;
    height:230px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    text-align:center;
    line-height:1.5em;
    padding:5px;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
}

 .sign-up {
    width:150px;
    height:40px;
    border:3px solid black;
    background:#22674A;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:7px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:40px;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif
}

.social{
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px black;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    width:250px;
    height:230px;
    margin-right:30px;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    padding:5px;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    margin-top:30px;

}

.social a {
    padding:15px;
}

.social h4 {
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-top:none;
}
.footer {
height:50px;
width:100%;
min-width:1100px;
background-color:black;
}

.footer p {
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    padding-top:15px;
}

.inner-footer {
    width:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/eWLyoIY.png"/></a></div>
            <div class="chapter-logo"><a><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RPIvgdD.png"/></a></div>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>

                <li class="dropdown"><a href="">About ▾</a>
                    <ul class = "sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="history.html">History</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="brothers.html">Brothers</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <li class = "dropdown"><a href="">Philanthropy ▾</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="kovacs.html">Kovacs Color Run</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="greekgod.html">Greek God</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                <li><a href="membership.html">Membership</a>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>

            </ul>
        </nav>


<div class="index">
    <div class ="letter">
        <p><b><br>Welcome to the official website for the New York Iota chapter of Phi Kappa Psi at Binghamton 

University! Here you will be able to learn about us, and get a brief introduction to Greek Life at 

Binghamton. If you have any questions or simply want to learn more information, feel free contact us at 

any time.</b></br> 

        <br><b><font color ="#22674A">Carl Hashem (Chapter President)</b></font></br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "news-section">
<div class ="news">

    <div class ="social">
        <h4 align="center">Connect</h4>
        <a href ="http://instagram.com/phipsibing"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/1GhbSOj.png"/></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/phi_psi_bing"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/oawoJtC.png"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/phipsi.sociallist?fref=ts"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2dAtAX3.png"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class = "greekgod">
        <h4 align = "center">Greek God</h4>
        <p align="center">On October 18th 2014, Anthony Leighton will be representing us in this years Greek God competition. All proceeds go to the Elizabeth Glazier Pediatric Aids Foundation.</p>

        <a href="https://www.payitsquare.com/collect-page/46106"><div class="donate-button">
        <p>Donate!</p>
        </div></a>
    </div>
    <div class = "kovacs">
        <h4 align="center">Kovacs Color Run</h4>
        <p align="center">The 5th Annual Steve Kovacs Color Run will take place on October 19th 2014. All proceeds are split between the Fairview Recovery Center and Childhood Development Center.</p>
        <a href="https://www.payitsquare.com/collect-page/41430"><div class="sign-up">
        <p>Sign Up!</p>
        </div></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
<div class ="footer">
<div class ="inner-footer">
        <p>© Phi Kappa Psi NY Iota Chapter. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I'm shocked that it works in any browser with all the errors it has, I seriously doubt it to be honest. For starters, the footer is after the closing body tag, you consider the li tag never should be closed, the concept of nested ul is unknown to you... well, I didn't test it, but again, seriously doubt this works in ANY browser. And if it does, it's just a lucky result that will break at the most minimal change

Comment: @Fabio thanks for the input but this doesn't answer my question. Its tested and works in the browsers fine. Just need help with the flexbox footer...

Comment: that's why I didn't answer and made a comment. Anyways, tested it in every browser, and just as I thought, it doesn't work, so I don't know how do you expect an answer on a minor aspect of something that is broken as a whole. Please don't take this in a bad way, I'm trying to help you, if you check my profile you'll see I answer LOTS of questions every day, but your question is simply IMPOSSIBLE to answer unless you fix your site first. Or put in other words: the answer to your question is: fix your site and it will probably work